# Is there something wrong with the Main or is it the GetGraph function?

Tags: c, file, search

```
    double d = atof(argv[1]);
    double diffPR = atof(argv[2]);
    int maxIterations = atoi(argv[3]);
    
    FILE *fp = fopen("collection.txt", "r"); 
    char *urlList[MAX]; 
    char tempStringOne[MAX];    

    for (int i = 0; fscanf(fp, "%s", tempStringOne) != EOF; i++)
    { 
        urlList[i] = malloc(strlen(tempStringOne) + 1); 
        strcpy(urlList[i], tempStringOne); 
    }
    fclose(fp); 
    
**    Graph urlGraph = GetGraph(); 
**
    int numUrls = checkNumberUrls();
    // for each URL in the collection (PR = 1/N)
    double *PR = malloc(numUrls * sizeof(double));
    for (int i = 0; i < numUrls; i++) {
        PR[i] = 1.0 / numUrls;
    }

    while (iteration < maxIterations && diff >= diffPR) {
        // calculate new PR values
        int t = iteration;
        // For each URL u in the collection PR(u,t+1) = (1-d)/N + d * sum(PR(v,t) / outDegree(v))
        double *newPR = malloc(numUrls * sizeof(double));
        for (int i = 0; i < numUrls; i++) {
            double sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < numUrls; j++) {
                if (isConnected(urlGraph, j, i)) {
                    sum += PR[j] / outDegree(urlGraph, j);
                }
            }
            newPR[i] = (1 - d) / numUrls + d * sum;
        }
        // calculate diff
        diff = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numUrls; i++) {
            diff += fabs(newPR[i] - PR[i]);
        }
        // update PR
        for (int i = 0; i < numUrls; i++) {
            PR[i] = newPR[i];
        }
        iteration++;
    }
```

```
Graph GetGraph()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("collection.txt", "r"); 
    char *urlList[MAX]; 
    char tempStringOne[MAX]; 
    
    
    for (int i = 0; fscanf(fp, "%s", tempStringOne) != EOF; i++)
    { 
        urlList[i] = malloc(strlen(tempStringOne) + 1); 
        strcpy(urlList[i], tempStringOne); 
    }
    fclose(fp);

    int numUrls = checkNumberUrls();
    Graph urlGraph = newGraph(numUrls);

    for (int i = 0; i < numUrls; i++) {
        char *url = urlList[i];
        char *filename = malloc(strlen(url) + 5);
        strcpy(filename, url);
        strcat(filename, ".txt");
        FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
        char tempStringTwo[MAX];
        while (fscanf(fp, "%s", tempStringTwo) != EOF) {
            if (strcmp(tempStringTwo, "#start") == 0) {
                fscanf(fp, "%s", tempStringTwo);
                while (strcmp(tempStringTwo, "#end") != 0) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < numUrls; j++) {
                        if (strcmp(tempStringTwo, urlList[j]) == 0) {
                            Edge e = {i, j};
                            insertEdge(urlGraph, e);
                        }
                    }
                    fscanf(fp, "%s", tempStringTwo);
                }
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return urlGraph;
}
```

The output of my program is incorrect, I'm trying to implement the PageRank algorithm in this code. Firstly the file information is stored into a Graph and then the pageRank is calculated. However my output does not match the correct output on the test files, so I suspect there is either something wrong with the mathematical operations in the main function or the GetGraph function. I'm not entirely sure and would like to find out.

Comment: start by adding your output and the desired output in the question

Comment: Give us a working program not two snippet; one of which is partial (missing main() and headers).